# Can we label encode values to only 0 or 1?

Tags: python

I want to ask if I have this table

| Name | Total_Request |
| --- | --- |
| A | 0 |
| B | 3 |
| C | 1 |
| D | 5 |

And I want to change or make new column from total_request with condition. If the user doesn't have total request then it is 0, but if the user have total request (any numbers > 0 such as 3, 1, 5 like the table above) then it's 1.

Basically I want to change the values to binary 0 or 1. Does it consider as label encoding eventhough the data is numerical? Whats syntax I should use?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
data={'Name':["A","B","C","D"],"total_request":[0,1,3,5]}
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
df["total_request"].where((df["total_request"]==0),1,inplace=True)
```

This will set anything that is not 0 to 1 `select all values which equal to zero otherwise if values not zero set those values to 1`